# Sharing OneDrive Access/Refresh Token between multiple apps

Tags: oauth, onedrive

I have went through the OneDrive API documentation but couldn't find anything on what I needed. Basically, we have developed two apps, one webapp and one mobile app for our product. We want to share the tokens between the two apps (if the user has already authorized for one app, he shouldn't need to re-authorize the second app).

The API settings page in [Microsoft Account Developer Center](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=193157) states that 
`Mobile client applications use a different OAuth 2.0 authentication flow.`

What is the recommended way to achieve this in OneDrive? Can the two apps use the same client id/secret and share the tokens? Or can they use different id/secrets and OneDrive provides a way to sync these tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this since the registration for web apps are different from the mobile app. You can do this if both are web or mobile apps.

When registering an app in Azure AD, the first option is to specify is your app web or mobile app, and then the flow and settings will be different based on the selected app type.

Hope this helps.